# Правильно ли держать cache в ServletContext?

Tags: java, servlet

Есть приложение которое занимается тем что отдает и редактирует профили пользователей. Мне надо организовать кеширование объектов `User` которые хранят личные данные, и отдавать их, когда это возможно, чтобы не лазать каждый раз в базу. Но возник вопрос:

Это вообще корректный подход использовать `ServletContext` для хранения кеша? Дело еще в том что никаких фреймворков не используется все на `Java Servlet API`. Какие тут типичные решения бывают где я  могу объект кеша держать?

Comment: Используйте на здоровье. (Кстати о здоровье. Сегодня день медицины. Поздравьте знакомых медиков, если у вас нет причин ненавидеть докторишек:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во-первых, при таком подходе можете забыть про масштабирование. Во-вторых, реализуя кэширование самостоятельно вы рано или поздно столкнётесь с целой кучей непростых вопросов типа инвалидации кэша и контроля объёма используемой памяти. Лучше использовать что-нибудь вроде [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/). Кроме того, механизм кэширования может предоставлять сервер приложений.

Comment: спасибо, интересная библиотека, и документация для чайников как я люблю)) А что вы имеете в виду под _инвалидацией кэша_?

Comment: За актуальностью кэша надо следить. И это не так просто, как может показаться на первый взгляд.